# Browser inside a browser

Tags: browser, javascript, window-manager, session, html5

My employees and I frequently need to open several internal web pages next to each other on the screen.

Currently we do this by opening several Chrome windows and spending time to arrange for example five such windows so one can see all of the at once on the desktop. One of these windows might show debugging information, another will show information directly from the database so one can track database writes, another one will have the web application itself for testing and so on.

I believe that we have something like 10 different ways that we need to organize the windows. Therefore, it would be great to have an HTML5 window manager (also called a "desktop inside a browser"), which would allow us to store a session where a single browser tab would open the five web pages, each webpage in its own "window inside one browser tab". I imagine that this should work using iframes and it would great if there was an URL bar in each window so one could visit any web page inside each window.

Does this exist or is it possible to create?

Comment: a possible workaround would be to create a batch file that starts [n] instances of chrome passing each a `--window-position` and `--window-size` parameter.

Comment: @Berend Yes, I have thought about it, but it is just not the elegant solution I was hoping for since it requires doing something on each computer and might be dependent upon the OS etc.

Comment: funny how 3D browsers from like 2009 had options to have multiple web pages shown at once soley for the purpose of navigating a site. picture being inside a 3d cube with 4 pages on the sides of the cube and the one main page in the center. Most 3D browsers were never completely finished, but it might be something that already does some of what you want.  You dont indicate if your looking for a browser, or (iframes) if you mostly want to make a webpage with multiple frames in it. Now most browsers Use 3D (gpu) but are only 2d.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I found something promising here: http://cryto.net/projects/jsde/demo/#
I was at least able to open several windows containing iframes:
http://screencast.com/t/mkvBVLRsfq0s

The link to download the code seems dead, but I have contacted the developer to see if I can still get the code. Hope he responds... In the meantime I attempted to use the "save web page" function, which got be quite far, but not all functions work. Specifically the multiple virtual desktops.

http://echo.nextapp.com/site/ also seems promising with extensive features.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this with tab stacking/tiling.

In [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com), its not perfect but the workflow I follow is

1. Bookmark the tabs I need to one bookmark folder (or tab stack em together and you can bookmark them at once.
2. Drag the tags together to combine them into one tab stack
3. Right click on the tab tile stack option and select "tile tab stack"

[image]

I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to figure out how to do it on other browsers with extensions, or to have a persistent way of doing so without needing to set it up each session